# Cell width and row height with multirow and rotated text

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, rotating

I would like to create the same table in latex:
[image: Table]

The first two and last two columns consist of a few words, but the two in the middle are made up of longer text.
In my code, I chose landscape orientation for the table.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.15\hsize}X}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Metrics}
\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{s|s|X||X|s|s}
\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Connectivity 1}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\shortstack[c]{Type of \\connection 1}}} 
& blabal blabal blabalbl abalblabal blabalbla balblaba lblabalbl abalbl abalbla balblabal   & blabal blabal blabalbl abalblabal blabalbla balblaba lblabalbl abalbl abalbla balblabal   
& \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\shortstack[c]{Type of \\connection 2}}} 
& \multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{Connectivity 2}} \\

&                    & 2      & 2.1     &                    & \\
&                    & 3      & 3.1     &                    & \\
&                    & 4      & 4.1     &                    & \\
\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{4-5}
& \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\shortstack[c]{Privileges \\ and rights 1}}}  
& 5                  & 5.1          
& \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{\shortstack[c]{Privileges \\ and rights 2}}} & \\
&                    & 6      & 6.1    &                    &  \\
&                    & 7      & 7.1    &                    &  \\
&                    & 8      & 8.1    &                    &  \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

There are several issues that I want to correct:

1. Despite the `origin=c` use in `\rotatebox`, it seems that the rotated texts are not centered
2. I must not use the midrule properly
3. Maybe there is a better way to define column types

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package, such as `\midrule` are intended to be used without vertical lines, hence the small gaps around intersections that you observe.

Comment: Entirely unrelated, but I wouldn't use rotated text inside of  rotated table. If you print the page containing the table, the rotated text will appear upside down if you look as the page in portrait orientation. It might be better to try to make sure the table fits onto the page in portrait orientation.

Comment: The issue regarding non centered rotated text is due to the uwe of `\multirow`. The first argument of `\multirow` is the number of lines of text, the `\multirow` cell spans, not the number of table rows. Thus, use `\multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Connectivity 1}}` instead of `\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Connectivity 1}}` and adapt the other `\multirow` commands accordingly.

Comment: Regarding the column types: I'd replace `s` with a simple `c` column type. If you plan on using `s`, which is basically just a narrower version of `X`, you must make sure that the sum of `\hsize` coefficient equals the number of `X` or derived column types in your table. (Currently, you use 6 `X` or similar type columns, but the coefficients only add up to 2.6) Using regular `c` type columns instead of `s` would be alot easier here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Metrics}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits=3pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{*{2}{w{c}{1cm}}*{2}{p{(\textwidth-4cm-12\tabcolsep-7\arrayrulewidth)/2}}*{2}{w{c}{1cm}}}
\Block{8-1}{\rotate \bfseries Connectivity 1}
& \Block{4-1}{\rotate Type of connection 1}
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& \Block{4-1}{\rotate \rotatebox{180}{Type of connection 2}}
& \Block{8-1}{\rotate \bfseries \rotatebox{180}{Connectivity 2}} \\
&& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla \\
&& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla \\
&& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla \\
& \Block{4-1}{\rotate Type of connection 1}
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& \Block{4-1}{\rotate \rotatebox{180}{Type of connection 2}}\\
&& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla \\
&& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla \\
&& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla 
& blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I compiled your code several times but I still have compilation errors. I'm working on Overleaf and I compiled it with pdfLateX compiler and other proposed compilers but it doesn't work.

Comment: Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of the Overleaf project. You can download that file on the SVN server of TeXLive : `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`